# Sharepoint Online Classifieds

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am very new to sharepoint online and our company would like to add a classified section for employees to sell items.

Currently I have a simple list set up but I have to give edit permissions to everyone to be able to add items and this means they can edit other listings. I have the Advanced Settings set to Create items and edit items that were created by the user. Not sure where else to go.

Also - is there a way to add a classified that would show a photo of the item that they have attached?

Comment: I SharePoint hosted in the building (or by your business) or is it in Office 365 (Microsoft’s cloud)?

Comment: While you can do this in SharePoint as described in the answers you have already, you might want to consider whether that is the best place for this type of thing - if you're using SharePoint Online as you say, then your company will also have access to Yammer, perhaps a simple Yammer group called "Buy and Sell" or similar would work for you instead?

Answer (score 0):

> but I have to give edit permissions

Are you testing with a user who might also have the "Design" Permission Level, Site Owner (Full Control) or Site Collection Administrator? Try testing with an non-admin user.

> Also - is there a way to add a classified that would show a photo

- Option 1: The photo would have to be uploaded to a library somewhere. You can then either add a "Hyperlink or Picture" column.
- Option 2: Add a Multiple Lines of Text column (with the Enhanced Rich Text" option) where the user could use the editing options to insert a picture. (The picture would be automatically uploaded to a folder in the Site Assets library.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create list with desired columns, use attachment to show images
2. create view / link to view item to show all info
3. Advanced Settings set to Create items and edit items that were created by the user - this setting should work try using non admin user
4. create content type to capture the required information
5. using design template get data from newly created content type and show as required.
6. Advanced Settings set to Create items and edit items that were created by the user